# batch: select top file from directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder full of config files called config#.json, where the # is a 2 digit base 15 number. I need some way to select one of the files, and put its name in a variable
I have been thinking about this for a while, but I'm not a very advanced batch programmer. There may be a way by using the results from a dir command, for example, if I get the last entry from the 8th line or something. I can get rid of the space in the name which may make it easier:

```
 Volume in drive C is Local Disk
 Volume Serial Number is 1A97-93E9

 Directory of C:\Users\hazzj\Google Drive\Home\Stuff\Apache-Server\htdocs\launcher_profiles

12/10/2016  05:44 PM    <DIR>          .
12/10/2016  05:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/10/2016  05:44 PM               707 config 11.json <- this bit here
12/10/2016  05:44 PM               707 config 12.json
12/10/2016  05:44 PM               707 config 13.json
12/10/2016  05:44 PM               707 config 14.json
12/10/2016  05:44 PM               707 config 15.json
12/10/2016  05:44 PM               707 config 16.json
12/10/2016  05:44 PM               707 config 17.json
12/10/2016  05:44 PM               707 config 18.json
12/10/2016  05:44 PM               707 config 19.json
         204 File(s)        144,228 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  344,802,287,616 bytes free
```

any help would me greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch script to Get First Filename from a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882993/batch-script-to-get-first-filename-from-a-directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "yourdirectoryname" ') do set "filename=%%a"
```

is the standard method to get that filename - if you want the last in directory

Modify the `dir` command by adding `/o:d` to find the last-by-date, `/o:-d` first-by-date, `/o:n` to find the last-by-name, `/o:-n` first-by-name - and there are other options - see `dir /?` from the prompt.

eg

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-n "yourdirectoryname" ') do set "filename=%%a"
```

(there are other ways)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the simplest answer.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /on config*.json') do set lastone=%%a
echo %lastone%
```

Basically, you're getting the bare (`/b`) directory listing (`dir`) of files (`/a-d`) in descending name order (`/on`), processing each line of the output of the command in `for /f` and `lastone` ends up set to, well, the last one.